# PostgreSQL import problem - all tables but one import

Tags: sql, postgresql, import

I have a reasonably sized postresql dump (around 270 mb) that I'm importing into a new database. All the tables import without issue except for one - the users table - and I'm neither sure what the problem is, nor what the best way to figure it out is. The tables after it import without error, so it's not as if it barf's on something and is unable to continue.

I've checked the log and there isn't much to go on:

```
2010-08-02 15:46:47 UTC STATEMENT:  COPY users ( omitting the fields.. ) FROM stdin;
2010-08-02 15:46:49 UTC LOG:  checkpoints are occurring too frequently (5 seconds apart)
2010-08-02 15:46:49 UTC HINT:  Consider increasing the configuration parameter "checkpoint_segments".
```

I'm not not a postgresql guru; most of my time is with mysql, so if there is something obvious to try, feel free to point it out! Not sure what to try next.

Thought that perhaps the orignal dump was from a different version that the one into which I'm attempting to import..but that seems like a lot of potentially unnecessary work to install another version.

All ideas welcome! Thanks..

Comment: Please show the exact error text.  The log warning generated during import is almost certainly harmless; presumably the import is just burning up transactions and forcing frequent WAL checkpoints.

Comment: Well, are the eror messages in groups: 'error, context, statement' in postgres? I do see the following which precedes the log message above:

2010-08-02 15:46:47 UTC ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(48)
2010-08-02 15:46:47 UTC CONTEXT:  COPY users, line 14929, column address2: "Zekai Gümüşdiş Mah. Fevzi Çakmak Cad. No:46 Emek"

Would one record stop the entire import?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using `psql` to do the load.  `psql` prints errors as it finds them with the prefix `ERROR` ... I usually collect the stderr and stdout of the import and grep or page through it.  `psql`'s error response depends on the value of `ON_ERROR_STOP`.  By default, that's disabled for non-interactive sessions of `psql`.  So the answer is likely to be no, the import would continue after encountering the error (although the contents of the enclosing transaction would be rolled back).

Comment: Thanks. I am using psql to do the load. The ON_ERROR_STOP is good to know..even though I was hoping that might be the reason. Must be something else then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at your comments it looks like an encoding problem. If your table has a char or varchar field with a fixed lenght and you try to insert a string that contains characters that get encoded in tow byte sequences in utf-8, the string looks longer to postgres if the encodings don't match.

make sure the input file and the database you have created are using the same encoding (I asume you want to use utf-8)

Comment: Yup, that did the trick! Thanks. I thought it might after seeing the error with the chars that were likely needing special encoding. But assumed new databases would default to UTF-8. They're not..they seem to default to SQL_ASCII.